# Crash on native packaged Mac JavaFX application

Tags: java, macos, javafx, nsapplication

I've got a JavaFX application I'm working on, it runs on Windows and Mac, I'm only seeing the issue on the Mac. I'm using JRE version 1.8.0_51.

Basically, when I'm not doing anything, and my application is in the background, sometimes it'll crash with the following stack trace:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff8e26d286 __pthread_kill + 10

1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff90d4d9b3 abort + 129

2   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001098d714f os::abort(bool) + 25

3   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001099f7c2c VMError::report_and_die() + 2250

4   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001098d8d7a JVM_handle_bsd_signal + 1131

5   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001098d5057 signalHandler(int, __siginfo*, void*) + 47

6   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff9889df1a _sigtramp + 26

7   libglass.dylib                  0x00000001e30295dd GlassScreenDidChangeScreenParameters + 157

8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8fe5f45c __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12

9   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8fd4f634 _CFXNotificationPost + 3140

10  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9089aaa1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66

11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91472e7e -[NSApplication _reactToScreenInvalidationImmediately:] + 379

12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff91472cc7 __44-[NSApplication _reactToScreenInvalidation:]_block_invoke + 75

13  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8fdbf8ec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12

14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8fdb19f5 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341

15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8fdb1536 __CFRunLoopRun + 1814

16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8fdb0bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296

17  libjli.dylib                    0x00000001093c48fb CreateExecutionEnvironment + 871

18  libjli.dylib                    0x00000001093c0644 JLI_Launch + 1952

19  libpackager.dylib               0x000000010938ef28 JavaVirtualMachine::StartJVM() + 3224

20  libpackager.dylib               0x00000001093952b3 start_launcher + 115

21  aer                             0x000000010930fcc8 main + 248

22  aer                             0x000000010930fbc4 start + 52
```

So, kind of hard to see what's going on here. It would appear that maybe my app is getting a notification that the screen has changed, but as far as I know, it hasn't. It's happened on two completely different Macs, one from 2011 and one from 2015, of completely different specs.

I don't think I've ever seen the issue running directly from NetBeans, it seems to only be when it's been packaged up as a Mac .app package and run from there.

Any thoughts/ideas most welcome.

Cheers

Garry

Comment: Intermittent failure suggests that a JavaFX scene graph is being accessed or modified from a thread other than the JavaFX Application thread.